# Cycle count of MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, battery

I have a 2020 MacBook Pro and the cycle count is at 210. I use it everyday for work and studying, so that makes sense I think.

The main question I wanna add here is that - is it okay to plug in devices to charge? My phone and airpods charge from my laptop, does that affect the battery in anyway? and does it increase the cycle count?

Will keeping it plugged in, help maintain the cycle count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cycle count is an indication of how many times the battery has discharged from 100% to 0%.

This includes partial discharges, so using the battery from 100% to 50%, then letting it charge back up to 100%, and then discharging to 50% again counts as ONE cycle.

It is not a 'ticking clock of death', but merely indicative of how the battery has been used.

If your MBP is connected to mains power, then charging other devices through it will not affect the battery in any way.